# Apply Function to create dataset from the dataframes column

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply, mapply

I have a dataset as shown below

[image: Given Dataset]

The challenge is to apply function on the columns from the 3rd column till the end.
The Function should Filter the dataset, column having only false and create a dataframe by the name as column name as shown below for the 3rd and 4th columns
and there are lot of columns available,i have to use apply function. can anyone give a solution.

[image: Dataframe from 3rd column]
[image: Dataframe from 4th column]

and so on for the rest of the columns.

Comment: share a reproducible data and not images! secondly what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `Map` to create a `list` of 'data.frame`s

```
nm1 <- names(df1)[3:ncol(df1)]
lst <- setNames(Map(function(x,y) {
               x1 <- cbind(df1[1:2], x)[!x,]
               names(x1)[3] <- y
               x1 },
          df1[3:ncol(df1)], nm1), nm1) 
lst
#$LOGICCOLUMN1
#  COLUMN1 COLUMN2 LOGICCOLUMN1
#6    FFFF    jjjj        FALSE
#8    HHHH    BBBB        FALSE

#$LOGICCOLUMN2
#  COLUMN1 COLUMN2 LOGICCOLUMN2
#1    AAAA    EEEE        FALSE
#4    DDDD    HHHH        FALSE
#5    EEEE    llll        FALSE

#$LOGICCOLUMN3
#   COLUMN1 COLUMN2 LOGICCOLUMN3
#2     BBBB    FFFF        FALSE
#8     HHHH    BBBB        FALSE
#10    jjjj    DDDD        FALSE
```

It is better to keep it as a list.  But if we really need to have objects in the global environment (not recommended)

```
list2env(lst, .GlobalEnv)
LOGICCOLUMN1
#  COLUMN1 COLUMN2 LOGICCOLUMN1
#6    FFFF    jjjj        FALSE
#8    HHHH    BBBB        FALSE
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(COLUMN1 = c("AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD", "EEEE", 
"FFFF", "GGGG", "HHHH", "llll", "jjjj"), COLUMN2 = c("EEEE", 
"FFFF", "GGGG", "HHHH", "llll", "jjjj", "AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", 
"DDDD"), LOGICCOLUMN1 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), LOGICCOLUMN2 = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), LOGICCOLUMN3 = c(TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)), .Names = c("COLUMN1", 
"COLUMN2", "LOGICCOLUMN1", "LOGICCOLUMN2", "LOGICCOLUMN3"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm getting error like 
        Error in names(x1)[3] <- y : object 'x1' not found

Comment: @Shivpe_R  Updated the post after correcting it.  Forgot to assign earlier

Answer (score 1):

this shall give you subsets of each variable. both TRUE and FALSE ones. Hope this helps you too!

I shall explain the code because you may have to make changes to this to work with your data. Please share a reproducible data for us to work on directly!
I'm iterating from 3rd column onwards and for each column I apply dlply to groupby TRUE/FALSE

```
library(plyr)
l=lapply(3:dim(df)[2], function(i) dlply(df[c(1:2,i)], colnames(df)[i])$`FALSE`)
names(l) <- colnames(df)[3:dim(df)[2]]
```

Comment: helpfull, will be more helpfull if it has the object name as corresponding column name.

Comment: are you referring to the names of each element of this list "l" ?

Comment: Is there any way to do by the use of column name instead of column Index ?

Comment: could you elaborate more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129370/discussion-between-joel-wilson-and-shivpe-r).

Answer (score 0):

This will be worked out When Colnames is required to use instead of column Index,However just additional functionality what @joel.wilson did

```
colmnnames <- c('COLUMN1','COLUMN2') 
c <- setdiff(colnames(dataset),colmnnames) 
l <- lapply(1:length(c), function(i) dlply(dataset[c(colmnnames,c[i])],colnames(dataset)[grep(c[i],colnames(dataset))])$`FALSE`) 
names(l) <- c 
l
```